# How to compare 2 values from lists within lists - Python

Tags: python, list, compare

I've got 2 lists that contain lists within them

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
list2 = [[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19]]
```

What I want to do is to take 1 value from a list is list1 and compare it to a value in list2. For example to see if one is greater than the other. Lets say I take 4 from list1 and I want to see if its smaller than 17 in list2. I'm just not sure how to specify to use that value. I have tried:

```
if list1[1[1]] < list2[2[0]]:
```

This doesn't work and I just need a simple way of being able to do this without creating a massive piece of code.

Comment: it should be as `if list1[1][1] < list2[2][0]:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is like this:

```py
if list1[1][1] < list2[2][0]:
```